# Update parameter inside child table room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I need help. I need to update lastStatus inside ConnectionWithPassenger which is part of the list of LocalConnectionsNearbyList. If I try to update it with the first query my build fails, I get an error: "There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: single_connection)". What is makes sence. But I can't also update it with the second query. I get another error: "no viable alternative at input 'UPDATE connections_new WHERE' public abstract void updateOut(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()". I don't want to change the database structure. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

```
@TypeConverters(ConnectionConverter::class)
@Entity(tableName = "connections_new")
data class LocalConnectionsNearbyList(
    @PrimaryKey
    var rideId: String,
    var connectionsWithPassengers: MutableList<ConnectionWithPassenger>,
)

@Entity(tableName = "single_connection")
data class ConnectionWithPassenger(
    @PrimaryKey
    val serverId: String,
    var connectionIdNearBy: String,
    var lastStatus: String,
    var lastTimeStamp: Long,
    var isSent: Boolean,
    var name:String,
    var image:String
)
```

DB:

```
@Database(
    entities = [
....
        LocalConnectionsNearbyList::class
    ], version = 2, exportSchema = false
)
```

Query idea 1:

```
 @Query("UPDATE single_connection SET lastStatus=:lastStatus WHERE connectionIdNearBy LIKE :lastStatus")
 fun updateOut(idOfConnection:String, lastStatus:String)
```

Query idea 2:

```
@Query("UPDATE connections_new WHERE rideId=:id SET lastStatus=:lastStatus WHERE connectionIdNearBy LIKE :lastStatus")
fun updateOut(idOfConnection:String, lastStatus:String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query doesn't work, because you probably don't have the `ConnectionWithPassenger` entity defined as an entity in the `entities = []` in the class annotated with `@Database`.

- if not the @Entity annotation is useless *(even damaging/frustating as such as it allows you to code `single_connection` as if it were a table)*.

The second query is trying to reference columns that are not in the connections_new table. That table has just two columns `rideId` and `connectionsWithPassengers`.

The data held in the `connectionsWithPassengers` column may well contain the lastStatus value (that depends upon the TypeConverter) but the **lastStatus** is not a column (likewise for the `connectionIdNearBy` column).

Using what you have you would have to either:-

- locate and change the value within the `connectionsWithPassengers` column (which SQL wise could be a nightmare but is dependant upon the TypeConverter as the TypeConverter determines how the data is saved in the column), or
- extract the `connectionsWithPassengers` list then extract/locate the respective `connectionsWithPassengers` object(s) from the list and then update the column with the amended list of `connectionsWithPassengers` objects.

**Example**

As much depends upon the TypeConverters in this example they are :-

```
@TypeConverter
fun fromConnectionWithPassengerListHolder(cwplh: ConnectionWithPassengerListHolder): String {
    return Gson().toJson(cwplh)
}
@TypeConverter
fun toConnectionWithPassengerListHolder(json: String): ConnectionWithPassengerListHolder {
    return Gson().fromJson(json,ConnectionWithPassengerListHolder::class.java)
}
```

A new class **ConnectionWithPassengerListHolder** has been added, as you there are issue with trying to use `var connectionsWithPassengers: MutableList<ConnectionWithPassenger>`

So **ConnectionWithPassengerListHolder** is :-

```
data class ConnectionWithPassengerListHolder (
    val connectionWithPassengerList: MutableList<ConnectionWithPassenger>
    )
```

Yo utilise the above **LocalConnectionsNearbyList** has been changed to be:-

```
@TypeConverters(ConnectionConverter::class)
@Entity(tableName = "connections_new")
data class LocalConnectionsNearbyList(
    @PrimaryKey
    var rideId: String,
    //var connectionsWithPassengers: MutableList<ConnectionWithPassenger>,
    var connectionsWithPassengers: ConnectionWithPassengerListHolder
)
```

The **AllDao** abstract class (rather than an interface) :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(localConnectionsNearbyList: LocalConnectionsNearbyList): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM connections_new WHERE rideId=:rideId")
    abstract fun getNewConnectionByRideId(rideId: String): LocalConnectionsNearbyList

    @Update
    abstract fun update(localConnectionsNearbyList: LocalConnectionsNearbyList): Int

    @Query("")
    @Transaction
    fun updateLastStatusOfConnectionNearby(rideId: String, connectionNearBy: String, newStatus: String) {
        var update_needed = false
        var lcnl: LocalConnectionsNearbyList = getNewConnectionByRideId(rideId)
        for (cwp: ConnectionWithPassenger in lcnl.connectionsWithPassengers.connectionWithPassengerList) {
            if (cwp.connectionIdNearBy == connectionNearBy) {
                cwp.lastStatus = newStatus
                update_needed = true
            }
        }
        if (update_needed) {
            update(lcnl)
        }
    }
}
```

and the following in an activity *( `.allowMainThreadQueries` used for brevity when building the database)*

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getAllDao()

    var lc1 = LocalConnectionsNearbyList("ride1",
        ConnectionWithPassengerListHolder(
            mutableListOf(
                ConnectionWithPassenger("S1","n1","NEW",0,false,"Fred","i1"),
                ConnectionWithPassenger("S2","n2","NEW",0,false,"Mary","i2"),
                ConnectionWithPassenger("S3","n3","NEW",0,false,"Jane","i3"),
                ConnectionWithPassenger("S4","n4","NEW",0,false,"Tom","i4")
            )
        )
    )
    dao.insert(lc1)
    dao.updateLastStatusOfConnectionNearby(lc1.rideId,"n3","CHANGED")
    dao.updateLastStatusOfConnectionNearby(lc1.rideId,"n1","ALTERED")

}
```

This will :-

1. get the database instance
2. get the AllDao instance
3. add a single `LocalConnectionsNearbyList` with 4 `ConnectionsWithPassenger`s (note the `ConnectionWithPassengerListHolder` is to circumvent the use of a List/Array for a column) to the database.
4. Change the 3rd `ConnectionWithPassenger`'s lastSatatus from NEW to **CHANGED** in the database.
5. Change the 1st `ConnectionWithPassenger`'s lastSatatus from NEW to **ALTERED** in the database.

**Note** the above is designed/intended to run only the once.

**Result**

After running the example above then using Android Studio's **App Inspection** :-

[image]

***As can be seen not all the data in the `connectionsWithPassengers` is displayed. Copying the data shows the data as*** :-

```
{"connectionWithPassengerList":[
    {"connectionIdNearBy":"n1","image":"i1","isSent":false,"lastStatus":"ALTERED","lastTimeStamp":0,"name":"Fred","serverId":"S1"},
    {"connectionIdNearBy":"n2","image":"i2","isSent":false,"lastStatus":"NEW","lastTimeStamp":0,"name":"Mary","serverId":"S2"},
    {"connectionIdNearBy":"n3","image":"i3","isSent":false,"lastStatus":"CHANGED","lastTimeStamp":0,"name":"Jane","serverId":"S3"},
    {"connectionIdNearBy":"n4","image":"i4","isSent":false,"lastStatus":"NEW","lastTimeStamp":0,"name":"Tom","serverId":"S4"}
    ]
}
```

- note the data has been split using line-feeds and tabs to make it more presentable.
- As can be seen the lastStatus for the 1st connectionWithPassengers has been changed to **ALTERED** and the 3rd has been changed to **CHANGED** with the other two unaltered as **NEW**.

Comment: Thank you for Mike for your detailed answer. If there is no easy way to do it, i'll try to process data before adding to db.